# SSo in liferay with third party application integrated with it

Tags: liferay

According to my requirement i want to Integrate third party application in liferay portal.

***i want to just display the applications inside the liferay portal , that applications might be facebook , linkedin or else or something else.
Tha major priority is when the user log in using same crediantial in liferay portal then these portlets that i integrated automatically be logged in at the time 
user log-in in liferay portal 
and then the user can use the third party application inside portal itself, so that the user dont have to go else*** , and he can easily operate their itself ....

This task that can be done by the SSO, i did integration by CAS, nothing i get any positive .

Looking for the best idea.

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/72372477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can  integrate this by using CAS.
PFA attachment of POC ,if anyone having a same requirement kindly refer this poc.

[Kindly refer this POC](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/72213192)